# Desktop keeps going into airplane mode since Ubuntu 17.10 upgrade

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, ubuntu-gnome, airplane-mode

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10, WiFi and Bluetooth continually turn off, and I have to reset airplane mode then manually restart them.

This would be annoying enough on a laptop, but this is a desktop computer, which I'm very unlikely to be using on an airplane. 
(Intel NUC).